# BeanIO - Set Properties for @Field to get new instance of ConfigurableTypeHandler

Tags: java, bean-io, typehandler

I am using BeanIO to write a fixed format file, which should contain some custom fields. These fields should use the same basic handler class, but they have slightly different parameters.

I have created a custom `@Record` that stores the data. Example:

```
@Record(minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = -1)
@Fields({
    @Field(name = "recordType", ordinal = 1, length = 2, rid = true, literal = "00")})         
public class CustomField{
    @Field(ordinal = 2, length = 8, padding = '0', align = Align.RIGHT, handlerclass = AmountHandler.class)
    private BigDecimal firstAmount;

    @Field(ordinal = 3, length = 8, padding = '0', align = Align.RIGHT, handlerclass = AmountHandler.class)
    private BigDecimal secondAmount;
}
```

I now want to customize the handlerclass based on the field that is going to use it. So I created this class:

```
public class AmountHandler implements ConfigurableTypeHandler{
    private int fraction, length;

    public AmountHandler (int length, int fraction){
        this.length = length;
        this.fraction = fraction;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeHandler newInstance(Properties properties) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        length = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("length"));
        fraction = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("fraction"));
        return new CustomHandler(length, fraction);;
    }
    //parse and format are not yet implemented. 
    @Override
    public Object parse(String text) throws TypeConversionException { return null;}

    @Override
    public String format(Object value) { return null; }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getType() { return BigDecimal.class; }
}
```

However, I can't seem to find any way to set the properties for each field.
How can I do this? Is there a way to define properties on a `@Field` type? Is there a better way to define a handler class for Objects with custom parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Create an instance of your `AmountHandler` for every variation you require in the same place where you define your `StreamBuilder`, for example:

```
AmountHandler amountHandler10_2 = new AmountHandler(10, 2);
AmountHandler amountHandler3_1 = new AmountHandler(3, 1);
```

You then register each instance with the `StreamBuilder`:

```
final StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder("builder_name")
  .format("xml")
  .addTypeHandler("amountHandler10_2", amountHandler10_2)
  .addTypeHandler("amountHandler3_1", amountHandler3_1)
  .addRecord(CustomField.class);
```

Then you reference the appropriate type handler on each `@Field`, using the name you have given the instance when registering it with the `StreamBuilder` and using the `handlerName` property instead of `handlerClass`:

```
@Field(ordinal = 2, length = 8, padding = '0', align = Align.RIGHT, handlerName = "amountHandler10_2")
private BigDecimal firstAmount;
@Field(ordinal = 3, length = 8, padding = '0', align = Align.RIGHT, handlerName = "amountHandler3_1")
private BigDecimal secondAmount;
```

PS: I see this was asked several years ago, somehow it showed up on my RSS feed as a question today. So, I thought, let me answer it in any case, should someone else come across this question.

A similar question and answer: [BeanIO: Format number with fixed length for integer and decimal places without separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70117545/2020886)